# Laravel web socket package and sending request to server

Tags: laravel, websocket

I have used the Laravel web socket package for the persistent chat application. when i call the api this will store the message on database and the message will be broadcast. if i send 10 messages then 10 times it call the server for storing the messages. I question arise in mind is that we are using web socket for the persistent messaging it means that it request one time to server and when the connection establish then it is not required to request the server again and again. my question is that, when the user first time send the message and connection is established then it is necessary to send the request to server for storing the data? is it possible that when the message is send and storing in database the server does not call again and again? I am very confused in this problem.

I am using laravel beyound web socket package for the live chat between different users

Comment: With websockets you establish the connection once. You still need to send data to the server every time it is necessary, possibly using an already open connection. I'm not entirely clear if this is what you're asking though